# Only show certain SurveyMonkey questions based on answers in checkbox selection

Tags: surveymonkey

How can I show users limited question sets based on what they select in a certain checkbox?

Example: Do you like: [checkbox]

- ice cream
- soda
- Pizza

and then only ask them about why and how much they like an item if they check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Question Skip Logic](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-create-conditional-skip-logic) but is only available on the Select, Gold or Platinum plans. It's not on the free plan.

Along with this you need to break up the survey into multiple pages to allow for the jumping across sections of questions.

> Question Skip Logic lets you skip respondents to a later page, or a specific question on a later page, based on their answer to a previous closed-ended question.

1. When you edit a question you'll see a Logic button.

   [image: logic on question]
2. Click on that to then see the options you can work with on skipping sections/pages of the survey based on certain responses.

   [image: logic options]

If you're allowing them to select multiple answers under a question, you can sort of enable it, but not really.

> You can apply Question Skip Logic to Multiple Choice questions with multiple answers allowed, but use caution. If a respondent chooses multiple answers, each with different logic paths, the survey can only skip them according to the logic path of the first answer choice in the list.

Question Skip Logic is much like a train on tracks coming to a fork. You can only choose to follow one path despite whatever conditions you may have collected/answered previously that would technically allow you to follow either track.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In that case, you have single choices from the user. In my example, I have a checkbox system with multiple answers selected. And so I need it to skip sets of questions but also show MULTIPLE sets of questions based on the user's MULTIPLE checkboxes.

Comment: You might be able to set it up, but that would not be really possible because the first answer matched will win which path to take. You can't split a person in two is the thinking