# How can I have conditional settings available when I use choice fields in check boxes?

Tags: cognito-forms

In my form I have two choice fields. The only difference is that the field on the left side has radio buttons and the field on the right side has check boxes. All other settings are identical.

Here is a picture of a simplified example:

[image: simplified example]

For my application it is important that the user can select more than one option in the second field, so I have to use check boxes there.

Now I add another field called "Country" which should be visible based on the selections in the second field, but when I open the conditional logic window, the object "Background" is not available.

[image: "Background" is not available]

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Conditional is a fork in the road. You can't follow two paths at the fork, so that's why you have to use radio

Comment: Very much like this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87886/only-show-certain-surveymonkey-questions-based-on-answers-in-checkbox-selection/

Comment: I do understand your point. However, the Check Box is still an Object in the code and the logic is True or False if any of the Check Boxes are Checked. So The Conditional could be Object.CheckBoxNumber.True

Comment: Moreover, I would like to use AND logic. So: If CheckBox 1 = True AND CheckBox 3 = True THEN ... This would not be possible with Radio Buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select Advanced Editor you can use this calculation

```
=Background.Contains("I am self employed")
```

The field will be visible whenever "I am self employed" is checked. If you want a field to show only when multiple criteria are selected you can use:

```
=Background.Contains("I am self employed") AND Background.Contains("I work for the CIA")
```

This will only show the field when both "I am self employed" and "I work for the CIA" is selected.